# Missing libc after using mkbundle

Tags: linux, mono, opensuse, mkbundle

I have a C# application developed using mono 3.0.6. Everything works perfectly.

I need to deploy this application to production desktops where I'm not allowed to install mono. So, I decided to use mkbundle, using the command

```
mkbundle -o myprog --deps --static myprog.exe
```

On the destination desktop, when I try to execute myprog, it gives me

```
Unhandled Exception: System.DllNotFoundException: libc
```

Obviously, both origin and target machines uses the same OpenSuse, except for the fact that target has no mono installed.

What is supposed I'm missing?

TIA.

Comment: Did you try deploying the mono config file in ~/.mono/config?

Comment: Ni, I didn't. Will deploy it and keep you informed. Thanks, @Gooseman

Comment: Did deploying the mono config file work?

Comment: I did. No changes. Same error persists... :(